# Parsing xml with many attributes using Java JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have following xml which I am trying to parse using JAXB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataSet Name="core_donor" Version="2-0" SchemaVersion="1-0" SchemaDate="2014-01-16">
<DataPoints>
    <DataPoint Name="donor_id" Value="105272" />
    <DataPoint Name="surname" Value="TWO" />
    <DataPoint Name="forename" Value="SCENARIO" />
    <DataSubSet Name="blood_gas">
        <DataPoints>
            <DataPoint Name="blood_gas_no" Value="1" />
            <DataPoint Name="blood_gas_date" Value="07/10/2014 10:15" />
        </DataPoints>
        <DataPoints>
            <DataPoint Name="blood_gas_no" Value="2" />
            <DataPoint Name="blood_gas_date" Value="07/10/2014 11:20" />
        </DataPoints>
    </DataSubSet>
    <DataSubSet Name="liver_function">
        <DataPoints>
            <DataPoint Name="liver_function_no" Value="1" />
            <DataPoint Name="liver_function_sample_date" Value="07/10/2014 11:10" />
        </DataPoints>
        <DataPoints>
            <DataPoint Name="liver_function_no" Value="2" />
            <DataPoint Name="liver_function_sample_date" Value="07/10/2014 13:52" />
        </DataPoints>
    </DataSubSet>
</DataPoints>
</DataSet>
```

I would be thankful if someone could point me how to achieve the parsing in java using JAXB.

Thanks!

Comment: lmgtfy: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/jaxb-tutorial-getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

For starters follow the below example

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

But  **DataPoints** will be your RootElement , if am not wrong also refererence
check some examples for DOM parsing to traverse over the child nodes and read them.